# Speed of gettid() on android

Tags: android, c++, performance, android-ndk

so basically I've written a custom allocator and a few tests on it to compare the speed of it to the stock malloc() function. On Windows I'm getting around 50-200 times faster allocations using the custom allocator compared to malloc, however on android it's around 4 times faster. The only difference between the code I've written for the two platforms is that to identify the current thread I'm using GetCurrentThreadId() in windows (which from what I've gathered is as efficient as grabbing an int from RAM), and gettid() for Android.

What I'm asking is, would gettid() be the most likely suspect for causing the disparity between the code on the two platforms? If so, how fast is gettid and is there a faster way to obtain a unique ID for the current thread?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that it is your Windows timings that are suspect. If there was a way to improve memory allocation by 50-200x one would expect it to have been provided already.

Comment: Have you tried microbenchmarking `gettid(2)`?  It should be extremely cheap on Linux, and may not even involve a user->kernel->user mode switch.  (Although the man page says there's no glibc wrapper for it, so that's unlikely unless Android is different.)  The necessary data / code for some syscalls (like `gettimeofday(2)`) is in the vdso page that the kernel maps into the address space of every process.  Anyway, try caching the value in a thread-local variable and see if that makes a speed diff for android.  If it does, then `gettid()` is slow, and you should cache the value in TLS.

Comment: `pthread_self(3)` may be faster.  POSIX allows `pthread_t` to be a struct, not an integer type, and I didn't check what it is on Linux.

Comment: I feel so stupid. I have no clue why I didn't benchmark gettid() itself. Turns out it's about 10 times slower than getcurrentthreadid(), which is negligible (also that doesn't even take into account that gettid() is running on my phone). Thanks for your guys' help.

Comment: On Android since https://android.git.corp.google.com/platform/bionic/+/5d9a7ba0dc9c24ed4e4efa9cac0e796fd524b308 the gettid(3) is significantly faster than the gettid(2), and would probably be a little faster on more platforms than custom caching with pthread_self(3) or pthread_getspecific(3).